# Delay between text messages in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am currently working on a user form and having issues getting any sort of delay to work as I intend it to.  I have the program check through multiple text boxes and display a message in a listbox.  The program sets the background color of the text box to match the color of the message.  This all works great, but all the messages are displayed at once.  I would like to pause between each message before displaying the next one.  I have tried using a timer, which would wait prior to displaying the first message, but then would display all messages at once after the timer expired.  I tried using a delay, but again the messages would all appear at once.  I also tried sleep, but since this is all one thread it will sleep the entire thread and then wake and display all messages at once.  No matter what I attempt the messages all display simultaneously.

The messages are being called from a void I created:

```
public void writeMessage(TextBox messageBox, string message, Color messageColor)
    {
    Brush colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(messageColor);
    messageBox.Background = colorBrush;
    if (statusList.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        list = new List<listColor>();
        list.Add(new listColor(message, new SolidColorBrush(messageColor)));
    }
    else
    {
        list = ((IEnumerable<listColor>)statusList.ItemsSource).ToList();
        if (!list[list.Count - 1].StatusItem.Equals(message))
        {
             list.Add(new listColor(message, new SolidColorBrush(messageColor)));
        }
    }
    statusList.ItemsSource = list;
    statusList.Items.Refresh();
    statusList.ScrollIntoView(statusList.Items[statusList.Items.Count - 1]);            
    }
```

On my button click I call the above void multiple times i.e.

```
writeMessage(textBox1, "Error!", Colors.Red);
writeMessage(textBox2, "Warning!", Colors.Blue);
```

I tried adding the timer and delay into the writeMessage void, but it would not space out the messages.  Anyone have any ideas or tips on how I could add a 2 second pause in the writeMessage void such that each time it is called it will wait for 2 seconds before continuing?

Comment: With your timer, did you tell the timer to start after the first message had been displayed?

Comment: Yes the timer would start at the top of the void and then stop inside the tick event.  all the void text was placed inside the tick event.

Comment: Why not use animations, since you're using WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what's going on in your user interface, but... if you're on .NET 4.5, you should just be able to do something like this:

```
writeMessage(textBox1, "Error!", Colors.Red);
await Task.Delay(1000);
writeMessage(textBox2, "Warning!", Colors.Blue);
```

The containing method will have to be marked `async`.

You may also benefit from following the MVVM pattern here. Consider looking into how to use bindings, observable collections, and data templates.

Comment: This works well.  I was attempting to call the delay inside the writeMessage void and it was not working.  Upon moving it outside as you have described everything works.

Comment: FYI If you were to place the `Task.Delay` inside your `writeMessage(...)` method, `writeMessage` would have to be marked `async` and then all calls to it would have to be awaited, e.g. `await writeMessage(textBox1, "Error!", Colors.Red); await writeMessage(textBox2, "Warning!", Colors.Blue);` otherwise they'll be executed immediately right after one another. For something to be awaitable, the return type must be `Task`.

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I wanted.